# Displaying values in a table on a web page

Tags: java, html, json, ajax, web

I wrote a java program that returns the values :(Hi,Hello,How,Are,You,Me,They,Them) as an array list.

I wrote a simple controller that takes these values and displays it as json on ***localhost:8090/greeting*** as follows:

**["Hi","Hello","How","Are","You","Me","They", "Them"]**

I want to display these values in the following format on a web page:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VApCb.png)

How do I achieve it?

Comment: @Arun P Johny Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java to iterate through the array and output the HTML tags for a table. For details on which tags to use, see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Can you please elaborate... @kmoser

Comment: @Mistletoe Elaborate on which part? You've stated that you've already written a Java program to retrieve the data and output it so I assume you're familiar with basic Java I/O. All that's left is to output HTML table tags (``<table>``, ``<tr>``, and ``<td>``) in the correct order, interspersed with your data.

If you make an attempt at writing the code, people here can help debug it. If you don't make any attempt, we can't really help you.